# Cannot get code to run on prototype board STM32F303x

Tags: stm32

... but it runs on Discovery F3 board (exact same MCU). BOOT0=Lo, NRST=Hi

The logfile generated when I try to upload code is as follows:

> Thu Apr 23, 2015 09:56:23: Loaded macro file: C:\Program Files\IAR
>
> Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\arm\config\debugger\ST\STM32F3xx.dmac
>
> Thu Apr 23, 2015 09:56:23: Loaded macro file: C:\Program Files\IAR
>
> Systems\Embedded Workbench
>
> 7.0\arm\config\flashloader\ST\FlashSTM32F3xx.mac  Thu Apr 23, 2015 09:56:25: ST-Link firmware too old  Thu Apr 23, 2015 09:56:25:
>
> Connected to ST-Link/V2  Firmware V2.J16.S4 (Probe no: 2798FD0D)  Thu
> Apr 23, 2015 09:56:25:
>
> Selecting SWD as current target interface.  Thu
> Apr 23, 2015 09:56:25:
>
> Thu Apr 23, 2015 09:56:25: Initial reset was performed  Thu Apr 23,
> 2015 09:56:25:
>
> Hardware watchdog  Thu Apr 23, 2015 09:56:25:
>
> (15.29 Kbytes/sec)  Thu Apr 23, 2015 09:56:25:
>
> C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench
> 7.0\arm\config\flashloader\ST\FlashSTM32F3xxRAM32K.out  Thu Apr 23, 2015 09:56:25:
>
> file: C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench
>
> 7.0\arm\config\flashloader\ST\FlashSTM32F3xx.mac  Thu Apr 23, 2015 09:56:27:
>
> to flash memory.Hardware reset with strategy 0 was performed-I- execUserFlashInit!  Thu Apr 23, 2015 09:56:25:
>
> -I-736 bytes downloadedLoaded debugee:Target reset  Thu Apr 23, 2015
> 09:56:27:
>
> C:\Users\dbruere\Documents\SoS\Debug\Exe\SoS.outUnloaded macroDownloaded

Comment: Can you provide more information about the hardware? What are the differences between your prototype board and the STM32F3Discovery?

Comment: The Discovery has a built in ST-Link, whereas I use an external ST-Link programmer. All my I/O is the same. Otherwise it's just a severely cut down version of the Discovery F3

Comment: I'm voting to close this question  because its way to underspecced to generate a meaningful answer.

Comment: Probably, but I cannot think of any more specific questions - just wondering whether anyone else has had this problem

Comment: The uploaded code seems OK (I can read it back from the MCU), but there may be some kind of difference in addressing when using Discovery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be that Discovery F3 provides an external 8MHz clock. My external clock is 16MHz, so I need to alter a divider in system_stm32f30x.c or alternatively use the internal HSI clock